# Does Android debug keystore work with release keystore?

Tags: android, android-keystore

I have two Android apps that are designed to work together. One calls some interface method in the other. When they are released, they will use the same release keystore, so that they can talk to each other. But now my question is, if one of my app is still debugging using the debug keystore, and the other is using the release keystore, should the debugging app be able to talk to the release app? I was told that I can't do this before, but now I was told that I can. I asked my colleague and searched online but can't get an explanation. Can someone explain this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they don't.  The debug keystore isn't anything special, its just a keystore that is automatically generated when you install Android Studio.  If you have two apps that only work with the same signing key, then they will not work if one is release and one is debug.

But please note:  depending on what you're doing, you don't need the same signing key to talk to each other.  You only need it if you're doing very specific things, like broadcasting a signed permission.

Comment: Thanks @Gabe. That cleared things up for me. Our software product line does require the same signing key to work together. I double checked with the other team that makes the other software, and I was told even if it's called release version, it's currently signed with the debug keystore... /facepalm So both apps are debug. That's why they work together.